# Extracting string from css locator

Tags: css

I have one question, i using css selector:

```
tbody[id='documentsForm:documentsTable_data'] tr[role='row'] td:nth-of-type(3)
```

it navigates me to below html code

```html
<td role="gridcell" style="" xpath="1">PPS/BAN/2018/1/00202/LPUN1NDRAFT/00001
   <br><label id="documentsForm:documentsTable:0:j_idt184" class="ui-outputlabel ui-widget orbeon-form-link o-list">[nawa-application-document/POLSKIE-POWROTY-UMOWA]</label>
</td>
```

i want to extract first string, in this example `"PPS/BAN/2018/1/00202/LPUN1NDRAFT/00001"`

if I use

```
listOfAvailableDocumentSignatures.get(0).getText()
```

it returns to me

```
"widoczne sygnatury dokumentow: PPN/PPO/2018/1/00007/NADRZ/POLS00001
[nawa-application-document/polskie-powroty-umowa]"
```

**Question** : How can i get only first String?

Comment: You should improve your answer...
1) add the full html table
2) say what you're using to get the string (I assume javascript)
3) add another tag, because this not a css question

Comment: Please add the code where you're trying to extract the string. Where does `listOfAvailableDocumentSignatures` come from?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
document.querySelector('[role="gridcell"]').firstChild.textContent;
```

or `document.querySelector('your-selector').firstChild.textContent;`

demo: https://codepen.io/iondrimba/pen/zVQaoZ?editors=1010